# How can i combine these two Django annotated queries into one?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two queries:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Comments(models.Model):
    user_field = models.ForeignKey(Users,on_delete=models.PROTECT,db_index=True, to_field='name')
    likedislike = models.SmallIntegerField(db_index=True)
```

bb1 = Users.objects.filter(comments__likedislike__gt=0).annotate(likes=Sum('comments__likedislike'))

bb2 = Users.objects.filter(comments__likedislike__lt=0).annotate(dislikes=Sum('comments__likedislike'))

how to combine them?

Comment: Likes and dislikes are combined into a single field on your comment model, `likedislike`? Why not have two separate fields as you are losing information that you seem to need?

Comment: yes it one field like this :   +234  or  -132  etc

Comment: Why not have separate fields? Your annotations are misleading, if a comment has 100 likes and 101 dislikes you are calculating 1 dislike and 0 likes

Comment: no. this 2 queries working correctly. I only have summary information for this field. if 100 likes and 101 dislikes then result -1 dislikes

Comment: what is your model looks like ?

Comment: class Users(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        registered = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
class Comments(models.Model):
        user_field = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True, to_field='name')
        content = models.TextField()
        published = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
        likedislike = models.SmallIntegerField(db_index=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a filter to [Sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#sum) to restrict which values are used, you can then have two filtered annotations in the same query

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Q
Users.objects.annotate(
    likes=Sum('comments__likedislike', filter=Q(comments__likedislike__gt=0)),
    dislikes=Sum('comments__likedislike', filter=Q(comments__likedislike__lt=0))
)
```